# как сделать запрос

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

есть таблица следующего вида:

запрос должен отобразить все движения на складе, за это отвечает столбец "Movement_Type"  (1 -товар прибыл, 0 убыл)

| "Date" | "Point_ID" | "tovar" | "Movement_Type" | "Sum_upack" | "tovar_Value" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-10 | склад1 | огурцы | 1 | 2.0 | 100.0 |
| 2021-04-10 | склад2 | огурцы | 1 | 2.0 | 100.0 |
| 2021-04-10 | склад3 | огурцы | 1 | 2.0 | 100.0 |
| 2021-04-10 | склад1 | помидоры | 1 | 2.0 | 200.0 |
| 2021-04-10 | склад2 | помидоры | 1 | 2.0 | 200.0 |
| 2021-04-10 | склад3 | груши | 1 | 4.0 | 150.0 |
| 2021-04-10 | склад2 | огурцы | 0 | 1.0 | 100.0 |
| 2021-04-10 | склад3 | огурцы | 0 | 2.0 | 100.0 |
| 2021-05-10 | склад1 | огурцы | 0 | 2.0 | 100.0 |
| 2021-05-10 | склад2 | огурцы | 1 | 3.0 | 100.0 |
| 2021-05-10 | склад1 | огурцы | 0 | 3.0 | 100.0 |
| 2021-05-10 | cклад3 | груши | 0 | 2.0 | 150.0 |
| 2021-05-10 | cклад2 | помидоры | 0 | 2.0 | 150.0 |
| 2021-05-10 | cклад1 | помидоры | 0 | 2.0 | 150.0 |
| 2021-05-10 | cклад1 | огурцы | 1 | 4.0 | 150.0 |
| 2021-06-10 | cклад1 | сливы | 1 | 4.0 | 150.0 |
| 2021-06-10 | cклад1 | сливы | 1 | 4.0 | 150.0 |
| 2021-07-10 | cклад1 | сливы | 1 | 2.0 | 150.0 |
| 2021-07-10 | cклад1 | сливы | 1 | 2.0 | 150.0 |
| 2021-08-10 | cклад1 | сливы | 0 | 2.0 | 150.0 |
| 2021-08-10 | cклад1 | сливы | 0 | 2.0 | 150.0 |

Собственно, 2 временные таблицы которые считают прибытие и убытие товаров со склада, после чего объединяется join ом

Сам запрос:

```
with prib as (select distinct date, 
       "Point_ID",
       "tovar",
        sum("Sum_upack") over (partition by date,"Point_ID","tovar") as prixod,
        count(*) over (partition by date,"Point_ID","tovar") as count_prixod,
        sum(sum_prixod) over (partition by date,"Point_ID","tovar") as rich  
from (select to_date ("Date",'YYYY-MM-DD') as date ,
             "Point_ID" ,
              "tovar",
               "Sum_upack",
               "tovar_Value" as sum_prixod
      from test_table_12
      where "Movement_Type"=1) as a_1
order by 1,2,3),
ub as (select distinct date, 
       "Point_ID",
       "tovar",
        sum("Sum_upack") over (partition by date,"Point_ID","tovar") as rasxod,
        count(*) over (partition by date,"Point_ID","tovar") as count_rasxod,
        sum(sum_prixod) over (partition by date,"Point_ID","tovar") as ubyt,
from (select to_date ("Date",'YYYY-MM-DD') as date ,
             "Point_ID" ,
              "tovar",
               "Pack_Sum",
               "tovar_Value" as sum_prixod
      from test_table_12
      where "Movement_Type"=0) as a_2
order by 1,2,3)
select prib.date,
      prib."Point_ID",
      prib."tovar",
      prib.prixod,
      ub.rasxod,
      prib.rich,
      ub.ubyt,
      coalesce (prib.prixod,0) - coalesce (ub.rasxod,0) as end_day
from prib
left outer join ub on prib.date = ub.date and prib."Point_ID" = ub."Point_ID" and prib."Point_ID" = ub."Point_ID"
```

результат работы следующий:

| "date" | "Point_ID" | "tovar" | prixod | rasxod | rich | ubyt | end_day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-10 | склад1 | огурцы | 2.0 | NULL | 100.0 | NULL | 2.0 |
| 2021-04-10 | склад1 | помидоры | 2.0 | NULL | 200.0 | NULL | 2.0 |
| 2021-04-10 | склад2 | огурцы | 2.0 | 1.0 | 100.0 | 100.0 | 1.0 |
| 2021-04-10 | склад2 | помидоры | 2.0 | 1.0 | 200.0 | 100.0 | 1.0 |
| 2021-04-10 | склад3 | груши | 4.0 | 2.0 | 150.0 | 100.0 | 2.0 |
| 2021-04-10 | склад3 | огурцы | 2.0 | 2.0 | 100.0 | 100.0 | 0.0 |
| 2021-05-10 | cклад1 | огурцы | 4.0 | 2.0 | 150.0 | 150.0 | 2.0 |
| 2021-05-10 | склад2 | огурцы | 3.0 | NULL | 100.0 | NULL | 3.0 |
| 2021-06-10 | cклад1 | сливы | 8.0 | NULL | 300.0 | NULL | 8.0 |
| 2021-07-10 | cклад1 | сливы | 4.0 | NULL | 300.0 | NULL | 4.0 |

все бы хорошо, но в исходной таблице есть 2 последние записи  с датой 2021-08-10 где показывается что товар убыл, ожидаю что в конце 2 таблице должна быть следующая строка:

| "date" | "Point_ID" | "tovar" | prixod | rasxod | rich | ubyt | end_day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-10 | cклад1 | сливы | NULL | 4.0 | NULL | 300.0 | 4.0 |

на end_day не обращайте внимание -это промежуточный столбец.

Я так понимаю что то с join надо сделать,я попробовал все - NULL выскакивает не там где надо

Comment: Мне лень до конца разбираться, скорее всего поможет `prib
FULL outer join ub`. А на самом деле, тут вообще никакие джойны не нужны, см. мой ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
  date, 
  "Point_ID",
  "tovar",
  sum(case MovementType when 0 then Sum_upack else 0 end) rasxod,
  sum(case MovementType when 1 then Sum_upack else 0 end) prixod,
  sum(case MovementType when 1 then Sum_upack else -Sum_upack end) end_day
from 
  test_table_12
group by
  date,"Point_ID","tovar"
order by
  date,"Point_ID","tovar"
```